# Probabilistic inequality for random walks

Tags: probability, random-walk

We have the following inequality
[image]

here $S_n$ is a simple symmetric random walk, and $b_n=[2n\log\log n]^{1/2}$, and $\xi(m)\rightarrow 1$.  I don't know how we get the two orange parts.  For the first one I really have no idea, for the second one I tried
\begin{align}
\frac{\alpha b_{\alpha^m}}{\sqrt{\alpha^{m+1}}}&=\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{\alpha^{m+1}}}\left[2\alpha^m \log\log \alpha^m\right]^{1/2}\\
&=\alpha\left[\frac{2\log\log \alpha^m}{\alpha}\right]^{1/2}\\
&=\alpha\left[\frac{2\log (m\log \alpha)}{\alpha}\right]^{1/2}
\end{align}
which doesn't give us the $\xi(m)$.

Comment: @OP: Much like your other question, can you link to the notes again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one is a lemma in the notes (Lemma 5.1), which, by using reflection principle, links the probability of a $\sup$ of a random walk up to time $n$ by the probability that it will end up in a particular place at time $n$.

For the second part, you are almost there: just write $\xi(m) = \frac{\log m + \log \log \alpha}{\log m}$.

Comment: So then $\log(m\log\alpha)=\xi(m)\log(m)$ right?  I can't see how this holds though.

Comment: I forgot a log factor. $\log(m \log \alpha) = \log m + \log \log \alpha$

Comment: So then what is $\xi(m)$?

Comment: It is the one on this answer.

Comment: I think it should be $\xi(m)=\frac{\log m+\log\log\alpha}{\log m}$, so the inverse.

Comment: Sure, I will change it.